# How to test ResizeObserver callback function using Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that uses the `ResizeObserver` to show/hide some styles.

the toggling of the styles is happening in a function the will be triggered by the `ResizeObserver` callback.

component.tsx

```
  private toggleStyles() {
        const applyStyles = some condition here...
        this.setState({ applyStyles });
  }

  private observeResize = () => {
        this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => this.toggleStyles());
        this.resizeObserver.observe(element to observe here..);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.observeResize();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.resizeObserver) {
            this.resizeObserver.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

I want to test the `ResizeObserver` callback that will trigger the `toggleStyles` function, but I'm not sure how can I trigger the resize on the element itself.

Comment: I reached this question while searching for a way to mock ResizeObserver for unit tests. Here is my answer in another (more popular) related question: stackoverflow.com/a/76220429/2528232